# Rails Find Through Association, Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

As an example, I have the following models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :full_address, :latitude, :longitude, :attr1 

  geocoded_by :full_address
  has_many :stores
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :full_address_changed?
end
```

and:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :attr2, :attr3
  belongs_to :location
end
```

I would like to be able to do a search for all stores that:

1. are nearby (using Geocoder on Location model)
2. meets some criteria on attr1 in Location model
3. meets some criteria on attr2,attr3 in Store model.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Why would a Location have a `has_many` relationship to stores?  Shouldn't it be the other way around?  As in, The apple store `has_many` locations.  Unless a location is a mall or something, I'm guessing there's only going to be one store there?

Comment: Sorry, this example was a bit misleading. Pleas see my explanation to your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still puzzled about your relationship setup... but say you had a setup like I mentioned above:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :attr2, :attr3
  has_many :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :full_address, :latitude, :longitude, :attr1 

  geocoded_by :full_address
  belongs_to :store
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :full_address_changed?
end
```

You could do something like this...

```
locations = Location.near(current_location.to_s, 20).where(:attr1 => 'a value')
stores_that_match = locations.find_all {|loc| loc.try(:store).try(:attr2) == 'value2' && loc.try(:store).try(:attr3) == 'value3' }.map(&:store)
```

That being said, the last part will be narrowed down using ruby in the code provided above..  If you want to narrow the criteria on the associated model as you're talking about using only a query, you're probably going to have to use [ActiveRecord's `find_by_sql` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql) and write the query out by hand.

Comment: Sorry, I realize my example was a little confusing. Location is meant to represent something like a golf country club, which may or may not have more than one course (store, in my example).

In this example, all courses at a country club share a few similar properties (location, club rating, etc), but have a few unique attributes of their own.

Comment: I may end up doing something like you suggest, and just duplicate storing the lat/long in each store even though there can be multiple stores at a location.